# Displaying a static image using React, Typescript and Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, typescript-typings, webpack-file-loader

I'm attempting to display an image in a React component as part of a project using webpack and webpack-dev-server.

So far I have completed the following steps:

- Used npm to install file-loader
- Updated webpack.config.js to add a loader for image files
- Imported the image I want into my component
- Used the import in my img tag

Having taken these steps, webpack fails to compile with a 'cannot find module' error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/App.tsx:4:26
    TS2307: Cannot find module '../images/kitten-header.jpg'.
```

My folder structure is as follows:

```
/dist
   /images
      kitten-header.jpg
   bundle.js
   bundle.js.map
/node_modules
   (content ignored for brevity)
/src
   /components
      App.tsx
   /images
      kitten-header.jpg
   /styles
      App.less
   index.tsx
index.html
package.json
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
```

The new loader that I added to my webpack.config.js is:

```
test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/, loader: "file-loader?name=./images/[name].[ext]"
```

I've imported the image file, in App.tsx, like this:

```
import kittenHeader from '../images/kitten-header.jpg';
```

...and used the import in an img tag like this:

```
<img src={ kittenHeader } />
```

**Note:** Full text of webpack.config.js and App.tsx were provided until I got a little bit closer to the answer and realized they weren't relevant (see update 1).

I assume I'm making some very trivial error with regards to the relative path in the import.  As you can imagine, I've tried various alternatives.

Can anyone provide some insight?

For reference, as I'm continuously hitting articles and questions relating to the wrong version of webpack, here are my versions:

- React 15.5.4
- Webpack 2.6.1
- Webpack-dev-server 2.4.5
- TypeScript 2.3.2

---

**Update 1:** 2017.06.05
So, looking at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793207/webpack-loader-cannot-find-module) and [this post on Medium](https://medium.com/@sapegin/css-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack-6b221ebe5f10), I've been able to identify that the problem lies not with how I've used webpack, but with that fact that I'm using TypeScript.  The error is a typescript error caused by the fact that the typescript compiler doesn't know what a .jpg file is.

Apparently, I'm going to need to provide a d.ts file or use a require statement.

Almost there...

Comment: Do you by any chance have a source repository we could use to reproduce the problem? That would be very handy.

Comment: If you are using webpack, you can install `@types/webpack-env` instead and fall back `require` instead of `import`. Unlike import, the string you pass to `require` doesn't get resolved by TypeScript.

Of course, using a `*.d.ts` is fine, too

Comment: Thank you @EvanSebastian, you're comment came in just as I was writing up my answer.  As you can see, my answer is incomplete.  Do you know how to write a d.ts for the jpg?  Is it possible to create a module to cover *.jpg or would a d.ts be required for every image file?

Comment: I also notice you've recommended `@types/webpack-env` , whilst I've used `@types/node`.  The node types do work.  What is the difference between these two, in terms of getting 'require' to work?  I assume they are simply two d.ts definitions of the same underlying 'require' implementation?

Comment: `@types/webpack-env` and `@types/node` are different, you use `@types/node` when you need to write NodeJS modules to make standard library typings available. `@types/webpack-env` is used when you are in a webpack bundled project. For instance, `require.ensure` will be available if you use `@types/webpack-env`

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll switch to `@types/webpack-env`.

Comment: In case you prefer to use .d.ts, this is the syntax https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#wildcard-character-in-module-names

You want `export default` to have type `string` in this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145887/discussion-between-montgomery-monty-jones-and-evan-sebastian).

Answer (score 14):

With regular require, this is how I use it in a tsx file:

```
const logo = require('../assets/logo.png');

...

<img alt='logo' style={{ width: 100 }} src={String(logo)} />
```

Hope this helps. `import`ing did not work for me, either.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I get it working:

```
// This declaration can be move in some common .d.ts file, will prevent tslint from throwing error
declare function require(path: string);

const SampleComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <img src={require('./styles/images/deadline.png')} alt="Test" />
  </div>
);
```

The way you proposed in your answer will end up writing modules declaration for each image file being placed in components.

Answer (score 2):

The error, `TS2307: Cannot find module '../images/kitten-header.jpg'`, is highlighting that the TypeScript compiler does not understand the import of a .jpg file.

The webpack configuration is fine, as evidenced by the image file being copied to the dist folder successfully despite the compile error.

There are two ways that we can resolve the issue.

**Firstly**, we could bypass the TypeScript import by using a 'require' statement.  To do this, the import...

```
import kittenHeader from '../images/kitten-header.jpg';
```

...can be replaced with a require...

```
const kittenHeader = require('../images/kitten-header.jpg');
```

...and that should be all that's needed.

**Note** that, in my case I also needed to install some typings to support the 'require' statement.  Without these, I was getting a `TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'` error.

Originally I used `@types/node`, as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35961176/301906), but @EvanSebastian pointed out that node is intended to support writing NodeJS modules, which is not what I'm doing (see comments on the question).

I tried `@types/webpack-env`, as suggested, but this resulted in a `TS2322: Type '{ src: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLProps<HTMLImageElement>'.` error against the src property of my image tag.

Most recently, I've switched to using `@types/requirejs`, which I'm hoping is focused enough to avoid including a load of inappropriate additional types. It is currently working:

```
npm install @types/requirejs --save-dev
```

**Alternatively**, we could keep the import and provide a `d.ts` file with type information declaring an appropriate module.  I've not been able to discover exactly what this file would look like.

Answer (score 0):

Add a typescript definition file anywhere in your src directory and (name it something like image.d.ts)
Export a module definition for jpeg files like so:

```
export module "*.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my code, in any React-Typescript component you want

```
import * as logo from './assests/icon.jpg';

const img = logo.default;

const Comp = ()=> {
    return <img src={img} alt="image" className="" />
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are ill-advised.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const logo = require('../../../assets/img/logo.svg')

 <img src={logo.default} style={{ width: "100%", height: "50px" }} alt="" />
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of your code to help readers understand how it addresses the question. When answering a question with several other answers, it also is useful to explain how your answer differs from or improves on the others.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to mcku's answer you can also use imports this way:

```
// @ts-ignore
import * as kittenHeader from '../images/kitten-header.jpg';
...
<img alt='logo' style={{ width: 100 }} src={logo} />
```

Although you have to ignore the warning.