# cannot import image with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using `create-react-app`, and I am struggling to load images. I am following the instructions as specified [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-images-fonts-and-files), but I keep seeing the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

Error in ./src/components/Home/imageIndex.ts
(1,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module './party.png'
```

Does anyone know why when I run `yarn start` my app continues to fail to compile?

I have a `Home` component and this is how I am importing the file:

```
import photo from './party.png';
```

The component is located in `src/components/Home/index.tsx` and the png file is located in `src/components/Home/party.png`.

here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "eai-reactjs-typescript-redux-starter",
  "description": "A ReactJS/TypeScript + Redux starter template with a detailed README describing how to use these technologies together and constructive code comments.",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "^2.8.0",
    "@types/jest": "^19.2.3",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.18",
    "@types/react": "^15.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^4.4.40",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.8.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.5.1",
    "react-scripts-ts": "1.4.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts-ts start",
    "build": "react-scripts-ts build",
    "test": "react-scripts-ts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts-ts eject"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Are you sure you've got the correct path? Also when you import an image via css (as is done in the example you mentioned) you need to give a path relative to the public folder and not the src folder. I have run into this problem several times.

An example using import:

```
import Image from './img.png'
...
// react example
...
render() {
    return (
        <img src={Image}/> // notice the curly
...
```

and not

```
<img src="Image"/>
```

Comment: As he is using typescript, he must also exclude his .png to be defined, as mentionned by pscanf here https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/172

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem and was able to solve with a require statement.

`const photo = require('./party.png');`

and then in your component use that like:

```js
render() {
    return (
        <img src={photo}/>
```

also see this post [Displaying a static image using React, Typescript and Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312170/displaying-a-static-image-using-react-typescript-and-webpack)

Answer (score 4):

As @archae0pteryx proposed it is much better to separate pictures from the code, so the project **public** folder should be used instead of **src**.

Here is how it works with **css**:

1. copy 'img.bmp' into /public
2. inside .css file/class: `background-image: url('/img.bmp');`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use something like this:

```
render() {
  // Note: this is an escape hatch and should be used sparingly!
  // Normally we recommend using `import` for getting asset URLs
  // as described in “Adding Images and Fonts” above this section.
  return <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/logo.png'} />;
}
```

Quoted directly from CRA [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system)

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Create-React-App` uses `url-loader` for files with size 10000 bytes

that works fine in the development environment, but in production reduce error.

For a production environment, you should change the value for the limit of bytes in order to enforce webpack use file-loader instead.

If you have to eject your app modify `webpack.config.prod.js` file and change the limit of `url-loader` to `10` and will work as well

```
{
 test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
 loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
 options: {
 limit: 10,
 name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My solution was to place the image into the Public folder. After that, I was able to read the image using:

`<img src="/pictureName.png" alt="Description" />`