# Does the url-loader plugin inline URLs in <img> tags, how?

Tags: web, webpack, urlloader, svelte-3

**Udate:**

Although I haven't been able to find out whether this is a feature or a bug. It seems `url-loader` can't process the assets used in the Svelte component unless those are loaded via `require`. So I would like to know what's the more common or recommended way to load/preprocess, using Webpack 4, a Svelte component source so that all image assets used in `src`/`url` in HTML tags and CSS styles get inlined, i.e. converted to use the embedded base64 data in the HTML or CSS output files.

**Original Question**

I want to have a tag `<img src="./assets/logo.png">` in a svelte component to be converted to `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iV...CC">` in the output, but if I add `url-loader` to my `webpack.config.js` file like so:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    //...
    {
      test: /logo.png/,
      loader: (process.stdout.write("!!!\n"), 'url-loader')
    }
```

The URL in `src` does still appear as `"./assets/logo.png"` in the output even is the console shows "!!!" during the webpack build process with no errors, why is `url-loader` not making the conversion? The file `logo.png` is about 3KB in size, but I'm not sure is that's the problem since it's small in size.

The image is being used [here](https://github.com/rraallvv/spark-payments-nimiq-webpack/blob/master/src/js/app.svelte#L8) like so:

```
<div id="app">
{#if path === '/'}
  <span on:click={navigateToSettings} id="menu"><div class="hamburger" /></span>
{/if}
{#if path === '/settings' && isStored()}
  <span on:click={cancel} id="menu"><div class="close" /></span>
{/if}
  <img class='logo' src='./assets/img/logo.png' alt='Spark'>
{#if connected}
  <span id="status" class="green">•</span>
{:else}
  <span id="status" class="red">•</span>
{/if}
  <div id="content">
    <RouterView />
  </div>
</div>
```

And I'm adding the `url-loader` rule [here](https://github.com/rraallvv/spark-payments-nimiq-webpack/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L107) before the rule for audio files:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    //...
    {
      test: /logo.png/,
      loader: (process.stdout.write("!!!\n"), 'url-loader')
    },
    {
      test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
      loader: 'url-loader'
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `webpack` and `url-loader` with any of modern frontend frameworks it is a common practice to use images via `require`.
Example from `react` world:

```
import iconMore from “../path_to_image/name_of_image.jpg”;

const Icon = (props) => {
  return <img src={iconMore} />
}
```

for more examples please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607227/cannot-import-image-with-create-react-app) question.

Also I found [`svelte-assets-preprocessor`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-assets-preprocessor#with-svelte-loader) - you can use it in pair with `url-loader` without direct `require`, but under the hood it is the same technique:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: 'images',
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(html|svelte)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'svelte-loader',
          options: {
            preprocess: require('svelte-assets-preprocessor')({ /* options */ exclude: [ (attr) => !/\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/.test(attr)} ])
          },
        },
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
```

Input

```
<img src="./example.png">
```

Output

```
<script>
    import ___ASSET___1 from './example.png';
</script> 

<img src="{___ASSET___1}">
```

Comment: Thanks. `svelte-assets-preprocessor` does the trick for urls in tags. I also wanted to inline assets in the <style></style> section but it seems [Svelte doesn't](https://github.com/pchynoweth/svelte-assets-preprocessor/issues/1) have support for variable interpolation in the component style section.