# I have a static image in a component, depending on the component where it is invoked, the image can be broken

Tags: reactjs

I have this component called `SearchBarScreen` :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./index.scss";
export const SearchBarScreen = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <img src="./assets/img/logo.png" className="nav_logo" alt="logo mercadolibre" />
    </>
  );
};
```

and my project has this structure:

[image]

depending on where I call this component, the image can be broken.

for example in the previous image it can be seen under the folder `src/components/items/components`, where it is called `SearchBarScreen`. For example, the image is shown broken on `ItemDetailScreen` but not on `ItemScreen`.

I always call it the same way in both components:

```
return (
  <>
    <SearchBarScreen props={props} />
  </>
);
```

In `ItemDetailScreen`

[image]

In `ItemDetailScreen`

[image]

Comment: Can you make a CodeSandbox replicating the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image loading to consistently work, you'll need to import the Image as if it was a component instead of the style you generally use with standard HTML.

Like so:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Logo from '../path/to/image';
import "./index.scss";

export const SearchBarScreen = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <img src={Logo} className="nav_logo" alt="logomercadolibre" />
    </>
  );
};
```

Edit:
If you absolutely *have* to use the public folder, which I don't recommend, here's how you do it: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

You'd basically make the path absolute instead of relative.

References:

- https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/
- [cannot import image with create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607227/cannot-import-image-with-create-react-app)

Comment: thanks man!.   `../path/to/image` in my case is `./assets/img/logo.png` Can you please see in the image that I uploaded of my structure, which is the correct route? I am getting a "cant resolve"  (the component is `SearchBarScreen` and the src was `<img src="./assets/img/logo.png"`

Comment: Yeah I've seen it. Is there a reason why you can't import the image and then put that as the source? Like is there a reason you need to use the public folder

Comment: I am new, I have seen courses and examples and the image is always in the public folder, I want to do what works for me. I do not know what to do?

Comment: or where should I put the image?

Comment: If you want to use the public folder, use an absolute math instead of a relative one.
So it'd be '/assets/img/logo.png' instead of './assets/img/logo.png. Does that work?

Comment: Also itd be great if you could make a Codesandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/ if that doesn't work. Basically make the simplest replication of  the issue you're having

Comment: excuse my ignorance and I hope not to bother you, I want to learn. My image is in the `public` folder, what is wrong with the path that I put doing what you tell me? `import Logo from" ./assets/img/logo.png ";`

Comment: Ah okay I see, so you can't import things outside of the 'src' folder. So if you want to import you'll have to move the logo to somewhere in your folder. Then it should work

Comment: This works! So is it good practice to save my images inside the "src" folder?

Comment: Glad it does! Generally speaking most of your images should probably be within the src folder. Here's a document explaining when to use the public folder - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#when-to-use-the-public-folder

Comment: If this solves your problem, just mark my answer as the solution in case someone else runs into it